# How is the blue screen called when scandisk runs before login?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

When scandisk is scheduled to run before login, it runs in a special blue screen. What is this special mode, does it have a name?

Do other programs run in this blue screen, or is it only for scandisk?

[image]

**Edit:** In the answer of [my other question](https://superuser.com/questions/896111/does-scandisk-produce-a-log-file-when-running-before-login) (the one which sparked this actually), they mentioned WinInit and WinLogon. Is that how that mode is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a multistring registry key that controls the execution of system programs at boot:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute`

By default this key is populated with:

`autocheck autochk *`

When chkdsk is called to run on the C: drive, the command is modified to include:

`autocheck autochk /p \??\C:`

Other applications other than chkdsk can be run, such as filesystem converters, boot time defragmenters, and rootkit cleaners.

Comment: Note the modified command is from a windows7 computer, you can tell chkdsk to run at boot by running "chkdsk C: /X

Comment: I found [this question mentioning BootExecute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151537/how-to-add-an-exe-path-to-the-windows-registry-to-get-executed-on-the-native-mo/23164301), in it they call it Native Mode. Is this how it's called?

Comment: OK, I found also https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447.aspx, they say applications running there are "native" and use only the NT API (ntdll.dll) and not Win32.

Comment: @sashoalm I would not call that native mode, but rather "pre-boot execution", but the programs do need to be compiled in a way that relines only on the kernel API, as they are not regular "Windows" programs.

Comment: [It's not really pre-boot](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-boot-process.html#User).